# Unable to create connection with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm trying to connect with cloud SQL but It always show error.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /cloudsql. Reason:

    Could not create connection to database server.
Caused by:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:140)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:148)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2330)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:140)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:148)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.azeem.endpoint.CloudSqlServlet.doGet(CloudSqlServlet.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:547)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.getInstance(SslSocketFactory.java:140)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:48)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:95)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:545)
    ... 57 more
Caused by:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:547)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.getInstance(SslSocketFactory.java:140)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:48)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:140)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:148)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.azeem.endpoint.CloudSqlServlet.doGet(CloudSqlServlet.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:95)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:545)
    ... 57 more
Caused by:

java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:95)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:545)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.getInstance(SslSocketFactory.java:140)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:48)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:140)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:148)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.azeem.endpoint.CloudSqlServlet.doGet(CloudSqlServlet.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Powered by Jetty://
```

I try to connect with mysql client and it's work fine and also try to connect with gcloud it also work. Then I download sample code from gitHub and try these code Everything is working then I copy the same code from sample but it's not work in existing project.

Here is my code.

**CloudSqlServlet.java**

```
package com.azeem.endpoint;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.Inet6Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

// [START example]
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CloudSqlServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException,
      ServletException {
    String path = req.getRequestURI();
    if (path.startsWith("/favicon.ico")) {
      return; // ignore the request for favicon.ico
    }
    // store only the first two octets of a users ip address
    String userIp = req.getRemoteAddr();
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(userIp);
    if (address instanceof Inet6Address) {
      // nest indexOf calls to find the second occurrence of a character in a string
      // an alternative is to use Apache Commons Lang: StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf()
      userIp = userIp.substring(0, userIp.indexOf(":", userIp.indexOf(":") + 1)) + ":*:*:*:*:*:*";
    } else if (address instanceof Inet4Address) {
      userIp = userIp.substring(0, userIp.indexOf(".", userIp.indexOf(".") + 1)) + ".*.*";
    }

    final String createTableSql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visits ( visit_id INT NOT NULL "
        + "AUTO_INCREMENT, user_ip VARCHAR(46) NOT NULL, timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL, "
        + "PRIMARY KEY (visit_id) )";
    final String createVisitSql = "INSERT INTO visits (user_ip, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?)";
    final String selectSql = "SELECT user_ip, timestamp FROM visits ORDER BY timestamp DESC "
        + "LIMIT 10";

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    String url;
    if (System
        .getProperty("com.google.appengine.runtime.version").startsWith("Google App Engine/")) {
      // Check the System properties to determine if we are running on appengine or not
      // Google App Engine sets a few system properties that will reliably be present on a remote
      // instance.
      url = System.getProperty("ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url");
      try {
        // Load the class that provides the new "jdbc:google:mysql://" prefix.
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Error loading Google JDBC Driver", e);
      }
    } else {
      // Set the url with the local MySQL database connection url when running locally
      url = System.getProperty("ae-cloudsql.local-database-url");
    }
    log("connecting to: " + url);
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        PreparedStatement statementCreateVisit = conn.prepareStatement(createVisitSql)) {
      conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(createTableSql);
      statementCreateVisit.setString(1, userIp);
      statementCreateVisit.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
      statementCreateVisit.executeUpdate();

      try (ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement(selectSql).executeQuery()) {
        out.print("Last 10 visits:\n");
        while (rs.next()) {
          String savedIp = rs.getString("user_ip");
          String timeStamp = rs.getString("timestamp");
          out.print("Time: " + timeStamp + " Addr: " + savedIp + "\n");
        }
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new ServletException("SQL error", e);
    }
  }
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<!-- Test Cloud SQL servlet -->   
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>cloudsql</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.azeem.endpoint.CloudSqlServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cloudsql</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cloudsql</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <sessions-enabled>false</sessions-enabled>

  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>

  <system-properties>
    <property name="ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url" value="jdbc:google:mysql://${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}/${database}?user=${user}&amp;password=${password}" />
    <property name="ae-cloudsql.local-database-url" value="jdbc:mysql://google/${database}?cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&amp;user=${user}&amp;password=${password}&amp;useSSL=false" />
  </system-properties>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <groupId>com.azeem.endpoint</groupId>
  <artifactId>EndPoint</artifactId>

  <properties>
    <!-- INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME from Cloud Console > SQL > Instance Details > Properties
     or gcloud sql instances describe <instance>
     project:region:instance for Cloud SQL 2nd Generation or
     project:instance        for Cloud SQL 1st Generation
-->
    <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>analog-premise-181709:asia-northeast1:instancename</INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
    <user>root</user>
    <password>password</password>
    <database>databasename</database>

    <appengine.maven.plugin.version>1.3.1</appengine.maven.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
  </properties>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.3.9</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>

  <!-- Driver injected at runtime by the use of <use-google-connector-j> in appengine-web.xml -->
    <dependency> <!-- ONLY USED LOCALY -->
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.42</version>  <!-- v5.x.x is for production, v6.x.x EAP X DevAPI -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
<groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
<artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.9.55</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
<artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
<version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
              <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I enter the correct instance name and password and database, here I just remove it.

Can you please let me know why this is not working. It's work fine when I run sample code.

Comment: If you're connecting from App Engine Standard, you are using the wrong library. Please follow the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/

Comment: I'm trying to connect with localhost. If I'm using wrong lib then why it's work when I run the sample code ? I just copy this code from samples

Comment: @Vadim Ok I changed the lib still not working. I found one difference when I run sample code it require `mvn appengine:devserver` but when I run my code it require `mvn appengine:run` is it a problem

Comment: I create the cloud enpoints project from eclipse using Gcloud plugin with java7, cloud endpoints work fine with this but sql not

Comment: You didn't mention you were running the application locally. Since it was tagged with "app engine" I assumed you were deploying this on app engine. In order to have the credentials available locally, you must run "gcloud auth application-default login".

Comment: @Vadim yes I already run this command and successfully save the credentials but still it's not working

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Vadim Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

you didn't create the default credentials , neither set the The environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` neither call credientials in your code, except that the default credential are provided with `Google API client libraries` which is not mentioned in your pom.xml, to add it:

```
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
     <version>1.22.0</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

[to start](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)

Comment: I add this `dependency` but still not working. I already create credentials with this command `gcloud auth application-default login`

Comment: Using one trick I'm able to use both cloud sql and endpoint. This time I add endpoint files in cloud sql and everything ok because cloud sql is already working. But still I don't know why it's not work when I add cloud sql file in endpoint ???